# Knockout - Check for specific text

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I´m new in the knockout framework and I guess I have a simple question for you.
My page get an AJAX result containing a mail address information:

```
["EMailAddress":"No mail address found"]
```

In my html page I now want to check, if there is an attribut called "EMailAddress" at all and if its text is not equal to "No mail address found".

It did the following which does not work:

```
<!-- ko if: EMailAddress-->
    <!-- ko if: EMailAddress != "No mail address found" -->
        <span data-bind="text: EMailAddress"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Can anyone of you tell me what I´m doing wrong? I always get the text "No mail address found" displayed!

Comment: Can you show what EMailAddress looks like in your view model please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that something in your code is not refreshing properly or is being evaluated incorrectly.  ie. a function (like an observable) is being treated as a property, or the value in the viewModel is not an observable at all.  But it is hard to tell without looking at the full code.

Here is a quick working example that accomplishes what you are trying to do that may help...

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>       
</head> 
<body>

<!-- ko if: validEmail() -->
    <span data-bind="text: email"></span>
<!-- /ko -->

    <button onclick="pretendNotFoundAjax()">Simulate Not Found</button>
    <button onclick="pretendSuccessfulAjax()">Simulate Found</button>       

    <script>
        var viewModel = {
            email : ko.observable(""),
            validEmail : function() {
                var emailValue = this.email();
                return  emailValue && emailValue != "No mail address found";
            }
        };

        $(function(){
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        });

        function pretendNotFoundAjax() {
            // imagine we've already performed an ajax call and the result was not found, which we set in the xhr callback in a way similar to the below line of code
            viewModel.email("No mail address found");
        }

        function pretendSuccessfulAjax() {
            // imagine we've already performed an ajax call and the result was successful, we got a valid email, which we set in the xhr callback in a way similar to the below line of code
            viewModel.email("validemail@domain.com");
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! But this is hard to implement for one like me which is new to this framework. I just had a look at the object I return. The property "EMailAddress" has a value "function observable()" and on expanding it I can see the _latestValue which contains "No mail address found". I guess that looks quite good but I´m still not able to check :-(

Comment: thats good news, you want EMailAddress to be an observable.  Try replacing your code with a call to check the value of the observable like this `<!-- ko if: EMailAddress() != "No mail address found" -->`.  That might work.  Please note the brackets `()` after EmailAddress.